# Pool Shares Formula

Tags: mining, mining-pools

I need a formula (for supportxmr.com) to calculate total earnings per Valid Share ,thanks.

--- XMR ---

- Block Reward :5.4116565613 XMR
- Network Difficulty : 79,367,458,558
- Network Hash Rate : 661.4 MH/s
- Pool Fees : 0.6 %
- Pool Hash Rate :84.97 MH/s

Comment: Just use a mining calculator like this one: https://whattomine.com/coins/101-xmr-cryptonight, it is just an aproximate

Comment: i need formula for programing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reward per valid share will be:

`block_reward * (1-pool_fees) / valid_shares`

Comment: this doesn't take into account different difficulties of shares. Any idea how this would be calculated?

Comment: I define "valid shares" here as the weighted total  of all solutions sent by the miners. If someone sends a valid share at difficulty 200, this counts as 200 shares. So if Alice sends just that single solution, she'll get 200 times the value from that formula. "valid_shares" is the total send by all miners. So 200 from Alice, plus... etc. If Alice was the only one mining, then the total valid shares is 200, so she gets 200 * block_reward * (1-fee) / 200, which is block_reward * (1-fee), the full block reward minus the pool fee, which matches the expected amount.

Comment: @user36303 Thank for clarification, can we calculate the reward per hash ? like coin-hive.com.
coin hive formula : (<solved_hashes>/<global_difficulty>) * <block_reward> * 0.7
and i mean Does it work for other pools ?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, and quite unclear. Please ask on a new post.